# How to show the following collection of set is an Algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-probability

suppose $\Omega=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is the outcome space of tossing an unbiased coin infinitely many times,
Define a map $\pi_n\colon\Omega\to\Omega_n$ denote the projection on the first n coordinates, where
$\Omega_n$={$(\omega_1,\omega_2,......,\omega_n)/$ $w_i =0$ or $1$} is a natural sample space describing n successive coin toss.
If $E\subseteq\Omega_n$ then $\pi_{n}^{-1}(E)$ is the typical n-dimensional cylinder in $\Omega$ and the collection
$A$=$\{\pi_{n}^{-1}(E)/ E\subseteq\Omega_n\}$,
we have to show that $A$ is an algebra. And I am having no idea how to start proving it. Any hint or suggestion will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: You need to show that the union of any two sets in A is in A and that the complement of a set in A is also in A.

Comment: that I know,but I am facing problem showing union and complement

Comment: If you don't specify what problems you have then I don't know how to answer, except by posting the solution.

Comment: I don't want a complete solution but at least if you give some hint regarding union and complement.

Comment: If $E\subset \Omega_n$ and $F\subset \Omega_n$ then surely $E\cup F\subset\Omega_n$ and $E^c\subset \Omega_n$, I don't see what else there is to do.

Comment: At least if we say that $E^c=\Omega_n-E$.